# Plot Pandas dataframe iterating over column names (as variables)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a Pandas dataframe with different settings depending on the column name.

My dataframe (topcount) is somethings like this

```
dateRep       Country1 Country2 Country3
20/03/2020        30       20      10
21/03/2020        40       28      15
```

I would like to plot column values on the y axis and dates on the x axis.

```
for country in list(topcount.columns):
    if country is 'Country3':
        topcount.plot(kind='line',x='dateRep',y='Country3',ax=ax,color='blue',linewidth=5)
    else:
        topcount.plot(kind='line',x='dateRep',y=country,ax=ax,linewidth=3)
```

The problem is that `y=country` is not interpreted as a dataframe column name.

Can I pass column names as a variable in this context or what is the right way to do it?

Comment: You can do `for country in topcount.columns[1:]:`

Comment: It works! Thanks a million! My original version was similar but it was missing the [1:]. That made the whole difference.